# Segment audio file into segments of 10s each using Java

Tags: java, audio

I have an audio file. I want to segment into 10 seconds each using java. Is there a simple way to do this

Comment: WHY -1 . Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: no, there isn't. It very much depends on the file format. Is it `.wav`, `.mp3` or yet something else? You'll need to understand the format, read data and write your 10s segments into separate files according to file format, possibly with decoding/encoding in-between. Look for some audio libraries - they'll ease your pain.